# How to find the worst performing queries in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2008-express

How to find the worst performing queries in SQL Server 2008?

I found the following example but it does not seem to work:

```
SELECT TOP 5 obj.name, max_logical_reads, max_elapsed_time
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) hnd
INNER JOIN sys.sysobjects obj on hnd.objectid = obj.id
ORDER BY max_logical_reads DESC
```

Taken from:

http://www.sqlservercurry.com/2010/03/top-5-costly-stored-procedures-in-sql.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

top 10 worst queries based on...:

```
SELECT TOP 10
    total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
        ,execution_count
        ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
        ,(SELECT
              SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                                                           WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                                                           ELSE statement_end_offset 
                                                       END -statement_start_offset)/2
                       ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
         ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 

--pick your criteria

ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
--ORDER BY AVG_Run_Time DESC
--ORDER BY execution_count DESC
```

Comment: +1 works pretty well for me.  Seem to be some duplicates in the rows returned but looks about right :)

Comment: duplicates in the rows could well be older versions of query plans that have been invalidated (variety of reasons, stats change being a common one) The plan isn't ejected from memory on invalidation so they show up. Another reason will be parameterization (or rather lack of) which means lots of similar queries with different parameters can be in the cache, occurs with ad-hoc SQL not stored procedures, but looks like lots of duplicates when it isn't.

Comment: @KM : intead of adding a slight alternative answer, how about joining in sys.dm_exec_query_plan and pulling the query plan - always worth extracting from the cache with the worst performing.

Answer (score 6):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135978.aspx) MSDN Magazine article provides excellent info on this topic.

Comment: @ThomasBratt You might need to change your database's compatibility level to run those queries. I did.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to find the worst performing queries by time taken, I'd use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats a
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) hnd
ORDER BY total_elapsed_time/execution_count DESC
```

However, finding the "worst" queries often requires a bit more probing into the `exec_query_stats` DMV. There are lots of things to consider:

1. Worst individual queries by time taken which the above query will yield.
2. Worst CPU hogs (if you are running high on CPU) which would order by `total_worker_time/execution_count`
3. Queries doing the most reads which are often queries that take the longest.

Now these queries will highlight queries that have poor performance but often you might have queries with "fair" performance but get called very frequently which drives down the overall performance of your app. To find these, order the above query by `total_elapsed` time (or `total_[whatever metric you are interested in]`) and do not divide by `execution_count`.

Answer (score 3):

Finding slow performing queries with SQL Profiler

- Start SQL Profiler (preferrably on the live database).
- File -> New Trace
- Choose SQL server
- Tab filter
- Optionally set a filter on the database name
- Start the profiler (RUN)
- Save the result in a table, for example: _Mytrace, preferrably on a database server that hasn't got much to do already
- Filter the select queries
- order them by duration
- Check exectution plan for this queries

Comment: running the profiler is certainly a good first option. once you get a good understanding of the profiler functionality, you can run traces.

Comment: just don't leave the profiler running for too long on the production server itself. in it's default mode, it is a bit of a resource hog.