# Finding columns to be indexed based on the queries run on the server

Tags: sql-server, indexing, database-performance

Is there any possibility to trace, most used column in every table on the SQL server?

The intention is, a query which suggests some columns to be indexed; Based on the usage of the column by the queries that run on server

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Find your [most expensive queries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499910/how-to-find-the-worst-performing-queries-in-sql-server-2008), run them in isolation in management studio and [show the execution plan](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan) and look for [suggested/missing indexes](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/07/dude-who-stole-my-missing-index-recommendation/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is not direct relationship between the most used column and the indexes.  The column can be used often, but if it has a poor selectivity the index will be useless.

You can use [Database Tuning Advisor](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173494(v=sql.105).aspx) to get optimal indexes set.