# A complete performance report before and after indexing on all tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, performance

Current, we have a tracking system that uses SQL Server 2012 database. None of the tables in the database are indexed. I believe if index is applied for those tables, the performance should improve.

In order to impress my boss with this idea, I would like to be able to generate a BEFORE and AFTER indexing performance report.

Is it a must that I have to select one or a few specific queries from our tracking system program and use them as the benchmark? Or I can just use some kind of data collector that collect certain performance data for say 1 week and then compare BEFORE index and AFTER index?

Comment: `"None of the tables in the database are indexed."` does it mean that all your tables are **HEAPs** (no clustered index)?

Comment: Hopefully they have primary keys ???

Comment: Right click the database name in SSMS and open the Report context menu. There's plenty to try and explore there. Some will tell you which views are the most expensive.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't done much SQL Server optimizations before I would suggest to try [Database Engine Tuning Advisror](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166575.aspx) - it will give you missing indexes hints.

As for the benchmark queries - you can identify the most expensive/popular queries on your SQL Server instance using `dm_exec_query_stats` management view. An example can be found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499910/how-to-find-the-worst-performing-queries-in-sql-server-2008)