# SQL query result truncated

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-performance

I have the following query to find bad performing queries

```
SELECT TOP 10
    total_worker_time/execution_count AS Avg_CPU_Time
        ,execution_count
        ,total_elapsed_time/execution_count as AVG_Run_Time
        ,(SELECT
              SUBSTRING(text,statement_start_offset/2,(CASE
                     WHEN statement_end_offset = -1 THEN LEN(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), text)) * 2 
                     ELSE statement_end_offset 
                               END -statement_start_offset)/2
                       ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle)
         ) AS query_text 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats 

--pick your criteria

ORDER BY Avg_CPU_Time DESC
--ORDER BY AVG_Run_Time DESC
--ORDER BY execution_count DESC
```

Found here: [How to find the worst performing queries in SQL Server 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2499910/how-to-find-the-worst-performing-queries-in-sql-server-2008)

However, when executed in Management Studio, the query_text is truncated and I cannot see the full query.
The queries found are very long, is there a way to still see the full query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.johnsansom.com/how-to-identify-the-most-costly-sql-server-queries-using-dmvs/

Comment: You can increase the query_text length specifying nvarchar(4000) instead of nvarchar(max), but you can't go beyond that value.

Comment: Thank you both! The link to johnsamson.com helped me